# passing a simon game from jQuery to vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Long story short, I made this Simon Game in a bootcamp a month ago in jQuery, but the days pass and I started to feel the necesity of translate it to pure vanilla javaScript.
the thing is that I feel stuck in the last part, when I have to check the answers of the game and add that to the gamePatern array and userChosenPattern.

here is the main part in jQuery

```js
var buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var gamePattern = [];
var userClickedPattern = [];
var started = false;
var level = 0;

$(document).keypress(function () {
  if (!started) {
    $("#level-title").text("level " + level);
    nextSequence();
    started = true;
  }
});

function nextSequence() {
  userClickedPattern = [];
  level++;
  $("#level-title").text("level " + level);
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var randomChosenColour = buttonColors[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour);
  $("#" + randomChosenColour)
    .fadeIn(100)
    .fadeOut(100)
    .fadeIn(100);
  playSound(randomChosenColour);
}

$(".btn").click(function () {
  var userChosenColor = $(this).attr("id");
  userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColor);
  playSound(userChosenColor);
  animatePress(userChosenColor);
  checkTheAnswer(userClickedPattern.length - 1);
});

function checkTheAnswer(currentLevel) {
  if (gamePattern[currentLevel] === userClickedPattern[currentLevel]) {
    console.log("success");
    if (userClickedPattern.length === gamePattern.length) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        nextSequence();
      }, 1000);
    }
  } else {
    $("body").addClass("game-over");
    setTimeout(function () {
      $("body").removeClass("game-over");
    }, 200);
    gameOverAudio();
    $("#level-title").text("Game Over, Press Any Key to Restart");
    $("#level-title").css("font-size", "2rem");
    startOver();
  }
}

function startOver() {
  level = 0;
  gamePattern = [];
  started = false;
}

function playSound(name) {
  var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + name + ".mp3");
  audio.play();
}
function gameOverAudio() {
  var gameOver = new Audio("sounds/wrong.mp3");
  gameOver.play();
}

function animatePress(currentColor) {
  $("#" + currentColor).addClass("pressed");
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("#" + currentColor).removeClass("pressed");
  }, 100);
}
```

and here is the same part and the whole code but in vanilla JS

```js
const buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
const gamePattern = [];
const userClickedPattern = [];
const started = false;
const level = 0;
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const levelTitle = document.getElementById("level-title");

// to start the game
document.addEventListener("keypress", () => {
  if (!started) {
    levelTitle.innerHTML = `level ${level}`;
    nextSequence();
    sarted = true;
  }
});

// generete the next sequence
function nextSequence() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var randomChosenColour = buttonColors[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour);
  let animationBtn = document.querySelector("#" + randomChosenColour);
  animationBtn.classList.add("FadeInFadeOut");
  setTimeout(() => {
    animationBtn.classList.remove("FadeInFadeOut");
  }, 50);
  playSound(randomChosenColour);
}

// here we detect which button is pressed by the user

var bTn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach((bt) => {
  bt.onclick = () => {
    let userChosenColor = bt.id;
    userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColor);
    playSound(userChosenColor);
    animatePress(userChosenColor);
    checkTheAnswer(userClickedPattern.length - 1);
  };
});

// check the answer and dynamic of the game
const checkTheAnswer = (currentLevel) => {
  if (gamePattern[currentLevel] === userClickedPattern[currentLevel]) {
    console.log("succes");
    if (userClickedPattern.length === gamePattern.length) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        nextSequence();
      }, 1000);
    }
  } else {
    body.classList.add("game-over");
    setTimeout(() => {
      body.classList.remove("game-over");
    }, 200);
    gameOverAudio();
    levelTitle.innerHTML = `Game Over, Press Any Key to Restart`;
    levelTitle.style.fontSize = "2rem";
    startOver();
  }
};

const startOver = () => {
  level = 0;
  gamePattern = [];
  started = false;
};

// adudio stuff
const playSound = (name) => {
  let audio = new Audio("sounds/" + name + ".mp3");
  audio.play();
};

function gameOverAudio() {
  var gameOver = new Audio("sounds/wrong.mp3");
  gameOver.play();
}

//animation in button
const animatePress = (currentColor) => {
  const buttons = document.querySelector(`#${currentColor}`);
  buttons.classList.add("pressed");
  setTimeout(() => {
    buttons.classList.remove("pressed");
  }, 100);
};
console.log(gamePattern);
console.log(userClickedPattern);
```

Also here is the game in my codepen, it’s without the sounds for obvious reasons.

[Simon Game](https://codepen.io/alandittler/full/KKzQKvJ)

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "feeling stuck"? What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: that i look the code for hours and hours and i dont get why for example in the jquery version inside the nextSecuence function I wirte userClickedPattern = [];
  level++; and works and why in the new version it give me an error

Comment: @AlanDittler You can't mutate a const variable.

Comment: Where do you declare `level` and `userClickedPattern`? Are these global variables declared outside of the code you have shown here?

Comment: @subarachnid The problem is that he declare level and userClickedPattern as const and then he tries assign new values.

Comment: @Carlos1232, I don't see any `const` declarations for these variables(?).

Comment: On the codepen he share.

Comment: @Carlos1232, Oh I see..

Comment: I added to the post the whole code to don't generate confusion